# Nodejs Express API - Mongoose performance response (slow)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, api, express, mongoose

I have a slow response time from mongoose find() request (only 4300 documents), My mongodb server is installed in Google Compute Engine (Ubuntu VM with 4 cores and 16 gb memory) and here is my get function  :

```
getBooks = async (req, res) => {
    await Book.find({}, (err, books) => {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(400).json({ success: false, error: err })
        }
        if (!books.length) {
            return res
                .status(404)
                .json({ success: false, error: `books not found` })
        }
        return res.status(200).json({ success: true, data: books})
    })
}
```

It takes **16.89** secondes !

Here is the result of .explain("executionStats") :

```
{
    "success": true,
    "data": [
        {
            "queryPlanner": {
                "plannerVersion": 1,
                "namespace": "Library.Books",
                "indexFilterSet": false,
                "parsedQuery": {},
                "winningPlan": {
                    "stage": "COLLSCAN",
                    "direction": "forward"
                },
                "rejectedPlans": []
            },
            "executionStats": {
                "executionSuccess": true,
                "nReturned": 4319,
                "executionTimeMillis": 1,
                "totalKeysExamined": 0,
                "totalDocsExamined": 4319,
                "executionStages": {
                    "stage": "COLLSCAN",
                    "nReturned": 4319,
                    "executionTimeMillisEstimate": 0,
                    "works": 4321,
                    "advanced": 4319,
                    "needTime": 1,
                    "needYield": 0,
                    "saveState": 33,
                    "restoreState": 33,
                    "isEOF": 1,
                    "invalidates": 0,
                    "direction": "forward",
                    "docsExamined": 4319
                },
                "allPlansExecution": []
            },
            "serverInfo": {
                "host": "mongodb-vm",
                "port": 27017,
                "version": "3.6.3",
                "gitVersion": ""
            },
            "ok": 1
        }
    ]
}
```

I added the lean() function and changed the query to :

```
getBooks = async (req, res) => {
    await Book.find({})
        .lean()
        .exec(function (err, books) {
            if (err) {
                return res.status(400).json({ success: false, error: err })
            }
            if (!books.length) {
                return res
                    .status(404)
                    .json({ success: false, error: `Books not found` })
            }
            return res.status(200).json({ success: true, data: books})
        });
}
```

Response time has become : **9.01** secondes .. still very slow !

Thanks

**EDIT 1** :

With lean() :

1. from my computer localhost testing on Postaman : between 9 and 15 secondes
2. same API deployed in Google App Engine testing on Postaman (instance calss F4_1G) : 2.58 secondes

Comment: Does this occur consistently or only when hitting the db the first time?

Comment: lean removes the step where mongoose add the function to the db objects, instead it returns a plain json Object

Comment: With lean() : 

1) from my computer localhost testing on Postaman : between 9 and 15 secondes
2) same API deployed in Google App Engine testing on Postaman (instance calss F4_1G) : 2.58 secondes